# freq parameter not presented in seasonal_decompose function

Tags: python, statsmodels

let us suppose we have following  code :

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data =  yf.download(tickers="FB", start="2016-1-1",end="2022-05-15",progress=False)
data.drop(["Open","Low","Close","Adj Close","Volume"],axis=1,inplace=True)
data.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(data.head())
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import  seasonal_decompose
result =seasonal_decompose(data["High"],model='multiplicative',freq=36)
estimated_trend_add = result.trend
estimated_seasonal_add = result.seasonal
estimated_residual_add = result.resid
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1)
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(15)
axes[0].plot(data['High'], label='Original')
axes[0].legend(loc='upper left')
axes[1].plot(estimated_trend_add, label='Trend')
axes[1].legend(loc='upper left')
axes[2].plot(estimated_seasonal_add, label='Cyclic')
axes[2].legend(loc='upper left')
axes[3].plot(estimated_residual_add, label='Residuals')
axes[3].legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

result of dataframe is given below :

```
                 High
Date                  
2015-12-31  106.169998
2016-01-04  102.239998
2016-01-05  103.709999
2016-01-06  103.769997
2016-01-07  101.430000
```

also it returns following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\facebook_real_prices.py", line 8, in <module>
    result =seasonal_decompose(data["High"],model='multiplicative',freq=36)
TypeError: seasonal_decompose() got an unexpected keyword argument 'freq'
```

instead i know that there is keyword period, are they same?generally we know that period is  1/frequency, but in this case how should i define period? or how can i create frequency index? please help me

Comment: You seem to have two questions here, one of them is why do you get an error message about freq, maybe freq is argument of extrapolate_trendint and not an argument name.

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html

Comment: i  have seen this argument on some sites  and therefore  i   was curious  whether this argument were  removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period argument in [seasonal_decompose](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.html#seasonal_decompose) is *periodicity* i.e after how long things start to repeat.

For example, time series data with a frequency of 1 hour would have a period of 24. If frequency was 3 hours, period would be 8 = (24 / 3).

In your case, it seems that the frequency is business days (Mon - Fri), which implies a period of 5.

Yeah, it seems that both weekends and holidays have been removed. But the `asfreq` method can be used to forwad-fill/back-fill blanks.
Specifying a period of 5 means that you expect values e.g on Mondays to be somewhat similar

If the input data is a `pandas.Series` with a datetime index, you might not need to specify a period:

```py
data = data.asfreq(pd.offsets.BDay(), method="pad")
```

But be warned, the [`statsmodels.tsa.tsatools.freq_to_period`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/865af604ebfd3a98ba9aa9fc1ff154527bc904bf/statsmodels/tsa/tsatools.py#L776)
function used internally in `seasonal_decompose` ignores the scale of frequency i.e. 3H and H are both treated as H. You can check this with:

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.tsatools import freq_to_period
assert freq_to_period("H") == freq_to_period("3H") == 24
```

I would recommend specifying the `period` argument directly in `seasonal_decompose` (5 in this case).

Comment: it seems also irregular period, days  are not regularly spaced, if i  take big period? for instance    36 days

Comment: You could pad blanks to ensure regular spacing. Taking a period of 36 means that you expect values 36 steps apart to be somewhat similar. Maybe try 20 for monthly.